# Is the QGIS connection with ArcGIS "mapserver" still working?

Tags: qgis, raster, import

I would like to add the Ocean Basemap to QGIS. I also found the other posts and I followed this procedure:

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Arcgis_rest

Hovewer when I put in the Python console the following code, an error message appears.

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer","raster")
```

I tried this link also

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=jsapi","raster")
```

I also tried using the gdal function:

```
gdal_translate "http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=jsapi" s.xml -of WMS
```

So, I wonder, Is this method still operational? Or did I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Same problem  ```GDAL provider: Cannot open GDAL dataset http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=jsapi: Failed connect to services.arcgisonline.com:80; No error
Raster layer: Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=jsapi```

Comment: Sorry I was off air when the Bounty came due. Based on an answer below it seems it's a corporate network issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically for Arcgis there are ways as below- documented [here](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Arcgis_rest). Lets try these methods.

1. `qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","my_raster")` works well.

   In this case you can omit `&pretty=true` from the url.
2. Another one is using [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).It uses raster tiles from the Tile Map Service(TMS) to render in qgis since it supports several raster formats as below-

[image: TMS Description]

I wrote [TMS Service description File](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms_arcgis_mapserver_tms.xml) and got the intended xml named `Ocean_Map.xml`(in windows writing in root i.e. C:\ may fail so try to other e.g. Desktop etc.)- I entered following command at `OSGeo4W Shell` and got file contains as below-

```
gdal_translate --debug on "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true" Ocean_Map.xml -of WMS
```

and got xml like

```
<GDAL_WMS>
  <Service name="TMS">
    <ServerUrl>http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/${z}/${y}/${x}
    </ServerUrl>
  </Service>
  <DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34278700</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34278700</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34278103</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34278103</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>16</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
  </DataWindow>
  <Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
  <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
  <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
  <Cache/>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

### Now drag this XML on QGIS that's all!

N.B. I am with QGIS 2.4.0 (Chugiak) 64 bit Windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me, using QGIS 2.10.1.  I copy the text below and paste it after >>> in the Python Console, then press Enter:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's still working:
[image: It works]

BUT if you are on an enterprise network or any network with some protections, I don't know exactly why but QGIS returns an error message:
[image: Doesn't work]

Comment: You might be able to add your corporate proxy settings into QGIS to enable it to work.

Comment: Yes, I have. But without success. However QGIS can connect to the plugin repository. Our corporate network is overprotected...

Comment: Any thoughts on the problems which come from enterprise networks?

Comment: No certainty... But I did some tests: I can access to services.arcgisonline.com with any browser, so the problem is specific to QGIS. Maybe the network settings are ignored by the Python console?